# splitting Pyspark dataframe column values with limit value from int in another column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, split, typeerror

I have a pyspark dataframe with a column of string values (complete file paths of arbitrary lengths and number of subdirectories), and a second column of integers:

```
\[...., "c:\\somedir\\somedir2\\somefile.someext", 3, ...\]
\[...., "c:\\somedir\\somedir2\\\\somedir3\\someotherfile.someext", 2, ...\]
etc.  
etc.  
etc.

...with column labels \[..., "thepath", "the_int", ...\]
```

I'm trying to create a new column, that uses the value in the "the_int" column as the "limit" parameter in pyspark.sql.functions.split as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# other code here

df1 = df1.withColumn("the_new_column", F.split("the_path", r'\\', df1.the_int))
```

but I get a 'TypeError: Column is not iterable' exception because of what I'm passing as the limit parameter to F.split.

I'm too new to pyspark to understand why (I don't completely understand the exception, or what I'm actually doing under the hood here). But is there a quick fix that I can do to "df1.the_int" to get it to act like an integer there?

If I replace the "df.the_int" with an integer value like 1, or 2, the code works...so the split command syntax is correct, and I think I'm using withColumn correctly...but retrieving the row's value for "the_int" in the way I'm doing it is the problem.

Comment: you could try the `expr()` way. it will accept column(s) as parameter(s).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly pass a column to [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html) , as limit excepts an `int` value , however you are passing a `Column` type , hence you see the exception.

To bypass this , you can use [expr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.expr.html) or [getItem](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.getItem.html) , depending on your usecase and intended outcome.

#### Data Generation

```
s = StringIO("""
the_path|the_int
c:\\somedir\\somedir2\\somefile.someext|3
c:\\somedir\\somedir2\\somefile.someext|2
c:\\somedir\\somedir2\\somefile.someext|1
c:\\somedir\\somedir2\\somedir3\\somedir4\\somedir5\\somefile.someext|5
c:\\somedir\\somedir2\\somedir3\\somedir4\\somedir5\\somefile.someext|10
""")

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter='|')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.show(truncate=False)

+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|the_path                                                       |the_int|
+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|c:\somedir\somedir2\somefile.someext                           |3      |
|c:\somedir\somedir2\somefile.someext                           |2      |
|c:\somedir\somedir2\somefile.someext                           |1      |
|c:\somedir\somedir2\somedir3\somedir4\somedir5\somefile.someext|5      |
|c:\somedir\somedir2\somedir3\somedir4\somedir5\somefile.someext|10     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

#### Expr

```
sparkDF.withColumn("the_new_column", F.expr("""SPLIT(the_path,'''\\\\\\\\''',the_int)""")).show()

+--------------------+-------+--------------------+
|            the_path|the_int|      the_new_column|
+--------------------+-------+--------------------+
|c:\somedir\somedi...|      3|[c:, somedir, som...|
|c:\somedir\somedi...|      2|[c:, somedir\some...|
|c:\somedir\somedi...|      1|[c:\somedir\somed...|
|c:\somedir\somedi...|      5|[c:, somedir, som...|
|c:\somedir\somedi...|     10|[c:, somedir, som...|
+--------------------+-------+--------------------+
```

#### GetItem

```
sparkDF.withColumn("the_new_column", F.split(F.col('the_path'),"\\\\").getItem(F.col('the_int'))).show(truncate=False)

+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------------+
|the_path                                                       |the_int|the_new_column  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------------+
|c:\somedir\somedir2\somefile.someext                           |3      |somefile.someext|
|c:\somedir\somedir2\somefile.someext                           |2      |somedir2        |
|c:\somedir\somedir2\somefile.someext                           |1      |somedir         |
|c:\somedir\somedir2\somedir3\somedir4\somedir5\somefile.someext|5      |somedir5        |
|c:\somedir\somedir2\somedir3\somedir4\somedir5\somefile.someext|10     |null            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------------+
```